# How to prevent onmouseover function from firing continuously

Tags: javascript, function, onmouseover

When I mouseover a button, a function activated by onmouseover fires continuously every fraction of a second. I want it to fire only once.

I need to use onmouseover on a button to call a submit function because I cannot use onclick because it interferes with another function that is called onclick. If I use onmouseout it works ok and only fires once, but onmouseout is not satisfactory for my purpose. I have tried other event handlers including onmouseenter, and onmousedown, but they suffer from the same problem. I also tried this: onmouseover="submitForm(); button.onmouseover = null;"

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {

 $("#pform").submit();

}
</script>

<input type="button" onmouseover="submitForm();" />
```

When the button is moused over, the function fires continuously, several times per second. I want it to fire only once.

Comment: I think you're looking for the "OnMouseEnter" event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event

Comment: I tried OnMouseEnter It causes the same problem as onmouseover

Comment: I think it is because when the form is submitted, the whole page is reloaded. Could you please check if this is the case? Please provide more information why onclick doesn't work.

Comment: @vago Then there's something else wrong with your code. The event will only be fired when your cursor enters the element.

Comment: Yes, admiraalit, I believe it is the case that the entire page is reloading. The reload icon of the browser blinks.

Comment: Robin, the event does fire when the cursor enters the element, but it keeps firing repeatedly until the cursor leaves the element. The bits of code I provided display this behavior.

Comment: Either try to prevent the submit (why do you need it?) or try to solve the problem you have with onclick (please provide more information about the other function it interferes with; maybe we can solve that problem)

Comment: The code you provided will fire repeatedly since you're using onmouseover. But it seems @www.admiraalit.nl solved it for you.

Comment: www.admiraalit.nl  I believe you do provide the explanation for what is happening - when the page refreshes after a submit, the cursor is still over the button, so the onmouseover event fires again. The onclick function is huge and very complex, and minified, I don;t understand much of it, it wasn't written by me. It is very sensitive to anything happening on the same button that activates it. Shankar's solution trashes it causing jibberish to appear on the screen. I don't know how to implement Vincent's solution in this case. Would it work when the problem is due to the page refreshing?

Comment: The form must be submitted. Shankar's solution trashes it causing jibberish to appear on the screen. I don't know how to implement Vincent's solution in this case. Would it work when the problem is due to the page refreshing?  I am trying to  submit the form prior to the button click because I want php to echo a message that login is required (thereby avoiding the popup blocker). Regarding sessionStorage, I want the user to be able to intentionally submit the form again in the same session.

Comment: Both of Shankar's solutions with localStorage and sessionStorage cause this to appear on the screen - something to do with the onclick function: 
").val(this.name).text(this.name)); });

Comment: In the future, please put comments about specific answers under those answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple logic to check whether the mouse over event enters first time. Use local storage, if local storage is no set initially, it is the first time the mouse over event.

else if local storage is already set to true, then don't trigger the form submit.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {

if(sessionStorage.getItem("mouse_over") == undefined){

 sessionStorage.setItem("mouse_over","true");
 $("#pform").submit();

}else{

}

}
</script>

<input type="button" onmouseover="submitForm();" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have multiple windows showing the same page. And it leaves garbage in memory when the window is closed. Using sessionStorage would be better. But anyway, this doesn't tackle the root cause. It is strange that a whole form is submitted only when the user hovers over a button. Onclick would be better, but there seems to be a problem with onclick.

Comment: I will edit it to session Storage. Yes on click is the better option. I don't know why @vago needs to use mouse over.

Comment: Now I have this -

Comment: admiraalit - I tried your code and it doesn't submit.  After many attempts using onclick and .click I have found it is either or: the javascript works and the submit doesn't or the submit works and the javascript doesn't. Both need the text in a textarea. I could stick with the submit onmouseout which works, if there were some way of displaying the message that login is required on top of the button other than echo from php that doesn't run afoul of the popup blocker, but it would need the login status from the server.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about the $(document).ready(function() { ... }); I don't have one, I know nothing about jquery since all my coding experience is from the dinosaur age. Should I have one? What should go in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(element).one('mouseover' function(){
 // your function here 
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24133054)

Comment: I assume that he needs a function that run once. but if you want me to provide reference from my answer here it is.. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_one.asp

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when you submit the form, the page is reloaded. After the reload, the mouse is still on the button and the event is fired again.

It is not common to use onmouseover to submit a form. You wrote that you don't use onclick, because it interferes with another function that is called onclick. If that is the only reason, then please try to prevent the interference as follows.

Change the button as follows:

```
<input type="button" id="clickbutton" />
```

Find the `$(document).ready(function() {` ... `});` in your page and add the following code inside:

```
$("#clickbutton").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#pform").submit();
});
```

Comment: I added this to the page <script>
$(document).ready(function() {$("#clickbutton").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#pform").submit();
});});
</script> and the id="clickbutton" to the button. Now the submit works perfectly but the javascript that runs onclick doesn't. I'm pretty sure that it is because they both need the text in the textarea of the form.

Comment: I banged my head against trying to prevent page refresh after submit, but failing that, I ended up using localSrorage to restore the form values.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad you have found a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your good advice for solving the continuous submit problem, but unfortumately it doesn't solve the problem that I can't run the text-to-voice javascript and the submit function both from the same click event.

Comment: Another solution maybe: Let PHP generate a global variable `isLoggedIn` which tells you whether the user is logged in or not. In the input tag, use a simple onclick event. In the event handler, instead of submitting the form, check the global variable and if the user is not logged in, show the message. You may also use onmouseover. Because you don't submit, you don't have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Admiraalit -
I'm trying your last suggestion. This is client side called onmouseover

```
    <script>
    function checkLoginStatus() {
        jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "checkstatus.php",
                success: function(res){
                    if(res == "0") {
                         alert("Login Required"); 
                    }
                }
        });
    }
    </script>
and this is checkstatus.php

    <?php
      session_start();
    echo "checking status";
      if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
      {
         echo "1";
      } else {
         echo "0";
      }
     ?>
```

I have verified with an alert box that checkLoginStatus() is being called, but nothing happens otherwise. What is wrong?

Comment: I may be trying to make this too complicated - maybe I could just echo my login message directly from php in checkstatus.php? but would there still need to be a return? something that happens for success: ? I am a fish out of water with jquery ajax and I have forgotten everything I knew about old-fashioned ajax :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a variable to track whether you have already submitted? For example:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var formSubmitted = false;
function submitForm() {
  if (!formSubmitted){
    $("#pform").submit();
    formSubmitted = true;
  }
}
</script>

<input type="button" onmouseover="submitForm();" />
```

That should ensure it only happens once (even if `submitForm()` is getting called many times).

Comment: This doesn't prevent the behavior, probably because with each refresh var formSubmitted gets reset to false.

Answer (score 0):

This works. I think the problem was the extra echo statement I put in checkstatus.php for testing.

```
<script>
function checkLoginStatus() {

    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkstatus.php",
            success: function(res){
                if(res == "0") {
                     alert("need to log in"); 
                }
            }
    });
}

</script>

<?php
  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
  {
     echo "1";
  } else {
     echo "0";
  }
 ?>

    <?php
      session_start();

      if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
      {
         echo "1";
      } else {
         echo "0";
      }
     ?>
```

This provides the not logged in message and I can submit using onmouseout so all is good. Thanks everyone.